To use `find` to find hidden files but ignore DS_Store ones
I try to use find to find files...

that are hidden using chflags, like chflags hidden my_file
or the filenames of which start with a period, like .my_file
and ignore macOS-specific .DS_Store files

The current version is
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -not -name '.DS_Store' -o -flags -hidden

But it doesn't exclude .DS_Store files. How to make it work?

Reorder and group your predicates:
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name .DS_Store \( -name '.*' -o -flags -hidden \)

Your original command,
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' ! -name .DS_Store -o -flags -hidden

... is the same as
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -name '.*' ! -name .DS_Store \) -o -flags -hidden

... and since the .DS_Store files have the hidden flag, these are listed.

Thanks, Kusalananda. Out of curiosity, are there any benefits of using ! instead of -not, apart from fewer keystrokes? I mean, they seem to work the same, but whereas ! is shorter, it is somewhat inconsistent with the rest of the find syntax, isn't it? Because there is no such thing like || instead of -or, for example.

@jsx97 There is -o (not ||) instead of -or; you are using it in the question.  I prefer using the standard operators -o and ! to the nonportable ones.
